# How can I convert BitArray to single int?

Tags: c#, .net, binary, integer, base-class-library

How can I convert [`BitArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx) to a single `int`?

Comment: BitArray to int Array or literally a BitArray to a single integer?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
private int getIntFromBitArray(BitArray bitArray)
{

    if (bitArray.Length > 32)
        throw new ArgumentException("Argument length shall be at most 32 bits.");

    int[] array = new int[1];
    bitArray.CopyTo(array, 0);
    return array[0];

}
```

Comment: Wow... I didn't think this would work to put all the bits into one integer value - but it does!

Comment: Refer this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3796/converting-binary-value-from-bitarray-to-an-int-and-back-in-c/3797#3797 Need to check the length of bitArray

Comment: Nice trick, however it could have issues related to byte order (endianess) on various platforms. It would be better to use `byte` array as destination for bit array copy and use `BitConverter.ToInt32(array, 0)` method afterwards.

Answer (score 11):

This version:

- works for up to 64 bits
- doesn't rely on knowledge of BitArray implementation details
- doesn't needlessly allocate memory
- doesn't throw any exceptions (feel free to add a check if you expect more bits)
- should be more than reasonably performant

Implementation:

```
public static ulong BitArrayToU64(BitArray ba)
{
    var len = Math.Min(64, ba.Count);
    ulong n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (ba.Get(i))
            n |= 1UL << i;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is better than the accepted solution from 7 years ago? Is it faster, more accurate, better at error handling, using less memory?

Answer (score 9):

```
private int getIntFromBitArray(BitArray bitArray)
{
    int value = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < bitArray.Count; i++)
    {
        if (bitArray[i])
            value += Convert.ToInt16(Math.Pow(2, i));
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why the OP should use this over the other solution?

Comment: @AustinHenley I wrote this solution for debug purposes. I can step through my code to see how the number is being converted. I'm not sure if you can do that with the first solution.

Comment: It's also interesting to know that the first solution is not available on WinRT (probably because of the way ARM processors save the numbers)

Comment: I have to use this because its not available on ARM.

Comment: The .NET Core stack may not have BitArray.CopyTo. That being said, why not `1 << i` rather than `Convert.ToInt16(Math.Pow(2, i))`?

Answer (score 1):

Reffering to this post (#43935747). A value X is short tpe whic I set two bits (6 and 10) like below: 
   short X=1;

```
        var result = X;
        var bitsToSet = new [ ] { 5,9 };
        foreach ( var bitToSet in bitsToSet )
            {
            result+=( short ) Math.Pow ( 2,bitToSet );
            }
        string binary = Convert.ToString ( result,2 );
```

Now I would like to read the specific all bits from Value X and put it in to an array or a bit type like bool Val1= bit1, bool Val2=bit2....

I am a newbie and I think it is pretty simple for you guyes..

Comment: OK but you should make it `|=` and `(short)(1 << bitToSet)` to make it more obvious at a glance. It's not like this code is incomprehensible, but it relies on the combination of some "carefully chosen coincidences" instead of just obviously doing the right thing.