# Operations on BitArray

Tags: c#, bitarray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How i can convert BitArray to single int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283180/how-i-can-convert-bitarray-to-single-int)

How can I read an integer to a `BitArray(6)` (assuming it can be contained) and how to convert a `BitArray(6)` to unsigned/signed integer.

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] bytes = { 0, 0, 0, 25 };

// If the system architecture is little-endian (that is, little end first),
// reverse the byte array.
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(bytes);

int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine("int: {0}", i);
// Output: int: 25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BitArray FromInt32(Int32 a)
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
    return new BitArray(bytes);
}
```

For reverse operaton [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283180/how-i-can-convert-bitarray-to-single-int) as mentioned before.