# Convert 13 bits in BitArray to signed integer then convert 4 bits in BitArray to integer

Tags: c#, arrays, integer, converters, bit

there is array of bits

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(17);
```

i want to take first 13 bit and convert into 13bits signed integer
and remainder in bits array 4 bits convert into 4 bits integer. 
How can I do it in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your bits are stored LSB first (e.g., left most in the BitArray), you can do something like this (borrowing off of this post: [How can I convert BitArray to single int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283180/how-i-can-convert-bitarray-to-single-int)).

```
int[] arr = new int[1];
bits.CopyTo(arr, 0);                 // assume that bits are stored LSB first
int first13Bits = arr[0] >> 4;       // shift off last 4 bits to leave top 13
int last4Bits = 0x0000000F & arr[0]; // mask off top 28 bits to leave bottom 4
```

Note that `first13Bits` should be signed, but `last4Bits` will not be signed here (since the top bits are masked off). **If your bits are stored MSB first** you will need to reverse the bits in the BitArray before you convert them (as CopyTo seems to assume they're stored LSB first).