# Last two bits in a BitArray of length 4 are being ignored when converting to int

Tags: c#, binary, int, bit, bitarray

Consider the following BitArray:

```
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(new Boolean[] {true, true, false, false});
```

and in binary equals:

```
1100
```

Now I want to convert this to an int and have tried to use the methods described on this page: [How can I convert BitArray to single int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283180/how-i-can-convert-bitarray-to-single-int)

However, both these methods converts `1100` to `3` instead of `12`. So it seems as if it ignores the last two bits and considers it of size 2 bit, for which of course the answer is `3`.

One of the methods on the linked page above, in action:

```
int[] array = new int[1];
bitArray.CopyTo(array, 0);
```

After executing the above, `bitArray` has the value 3.

How can I express in the code that I want it to consider all 4 bits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for `BitArray(bool[])` accepts the values in index order - and then `CopyTo` uses them in the traditional significance (so `bitArray[0]` is the least significant bit) - so your `true`, `true`, `false`, `false` ends up meaning 0011 in binary, *not* 1100.

It's not ignoring the last two bits - it's just treating your initial array in the opposite order to the one you expected.

If you want it to make the first-specified value as the *most* significant value when converting the bits to integers, you'll need to reverse your input array.