# Convert a BitArray to Int in C#

Tags: c#, int, bitarray

In C# I have a BitArray that stores a value of 5 as follows

`BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(new int[] { 5});`

I want to retrieve the value of 5 from the BitArray as an integer as follows:

```
int myInt = //some operation on bitArray goes here
```

What would be a fast method of retrieving it? This operation will be repeated heavily so performance is important.

Comment: The answer here has additional checks for length which I don't need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283180/how-can-i-convert-bitarray-to-single-int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy the bit array to an int array and take the first element.

```
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(new int[] { 5 });
int[] array = new int[1];
bitArray.CopyTo(array, 0);
int result = array[0];
```

Comment: Is there an equally fast method that doesn't require me to declare an array?

Comment: I don't know a faster solution. Think about using C or C++ if this is not fast enought.

Comment: There is no concept of endianness in the solution!